# Converting a String to a Apache Avro GenericRecord

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro

Can someone give advices on how to convert a `String` into a `GenericRecord`? I would like to convert my records to avro and put them into a Kafka topic.

I used to have it as a `String` (I replaced it with `GenericRecord`).

```
def producerMethod(socket: Seq[Socket], prot: String): KafkaProducer[String, GenericRecord] =
producer(params(socket, prot))

def producerMethod(params: Map[String, String]): KafkaProducer[String, GenericRecord] =
new KafkaProducer[String, GenericRecord](params.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]].asJava)
```

I also have an `apply` method, which has an iterator in it. 
It iterates over strings and adds the values in a tuple.

In the end I send the data to a topic:

The results variable is a `String` but I added "asInstanceOf"

```
result.send(new ProducerRecord[String,GenericRecord](topic,key,results.asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]))
```

Here is my iterator:

```
iterator.foreach { tuple =>
      val (keyinfo, info, Worked(outinfo, _)) = tuple
      val (key, results) = keyResultToString(keyinfo, info, outinfo)
      result.send(new ProducerRecord[String,GenericRecord](topic,key,results.asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]))
    }
```

Everything works, when I replace the GenericRecord back to String. But not if I would like to convert it to a GenericRecord

Comment: few things are not clear here: you used to put Strings into your topic and you want to put in "things" serialized with Avro? What's you're Kafka producer configuration?

Comment: do you mean this Information?       "bootstrap.servers" -> servers,
      "security.protocol" -> prot,
      "max.request.size" -> maxMessageSize,
      "key.serializer" -> stringSerializer,
      "value.serializer" -> stringKafkaAvroSerializer,
      "schema.registry.base.url " -> schemaURL

Comment: I would like to convert the data into binary avro datatype. I receive the data as String. I use following serializer: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" and "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"

Comment: Did you take a look at this example https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serializer-formatter.html ? (though it's in Java, it should be easy to port it to Scala)

Comment: Yes I saw this example. But I don't know how to correctly convert my tupel that stores the values in String (to GenericRecords)

Comment: I don't see any tuple in your example... but assuming you have a tuple representing key and value, `val x = ("k", "v")` and assuming you've got your Avro schema with you, you can just do `let avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema)` and then
`avroRecord.put(x._1, x._2)`

Comment: I added the tupel

Comment: What does `keyResultToString` do?

Comment: keyResultToString: ((Key, Info, Result) => (String, String)) with Serializable)

Comment: Try
```
val (key, results) = keyResultToString(keyinfo, info, outinfo)
val avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema)
avroRecord.put(key, results)
result.send(new ProducerRecord[String, GenericRecord](topic, key, avroRecord))
```